# Sprachübergreifende Duplikate in Fragen und Sprachwahl beim Antworten

Tags: discussion, duplicates, downvoting, not-an-answer

In [What to do with duplicate questions in another language?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/5437) lese ich, dass offenbar Konsens besteht hinsichtlich der Eigenständigkeit inhaltlich gleicher Fragen, sofern sie in unterschiedlichen Sprachen gestellt werden. Die Lösung mit dem Verweis zwischen den Sprachvarianten ist sehr nützlich.

Ist eine **ergänzende Konvention sinnvoll, Antworten in abweichender Sprache** abzuweisen oder zurückzudrängen?

So sehe auf die Frage in [Gender of country names without articles](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/10836/5437) (Englisch)

- eine Antwort auf Deutsch https://german.stackexchange.com/a/10852/5437
- und einen Quasi-Verweis auf die korrespondierende Frage (samt Antwort) 
  [»2014 spielt Deutschland gegen Portugal, {das · der · die} zu stark ist.«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9285/5437) (Deutsch)

An beiden finde ich keinerlei kritische Anmerkung zum Sprachwechsel. Aus meiner Sicht ergänzen sich die Verfahrensweisen (Auseinanderhalten der Fragen und Toleranz gegenüber "fremdsprachigen" Antworten) nicht.

Umgekehrt hielte ich es für nützlich, Antworten **an die sprachlich passende Frage zu verweisen** (durch Kommentare, Not-an-answer-Flags oder Down-Voten). Gibt er hierzu Überlegungen bzw. Gegenanzeigen?

Comment: [Hier der meta-Thread](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) der besagt, dass bitte in der entsprechenden Sprache geantwortet werden soll. Wie man mit trotzdem anderssprachigen Antworten umgehen soll (immerhin steht da ja nur "should") beantwortet er mE nicht ^^.